# MongoServerError: Plan executor error during findAndModify :: caused by :: Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field _id

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

Everytime my command ends I get this error. I have no idea what to do, the command gas been working before but it went downhill when I added a new function that updated another array.

MongoServerError: Plan executor error during findAndModify :: caused by :: Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'

at Connection.onMessage (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:230:30)

at MessageStream. (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:61:60)

at MessageStream.emit (node:events:527:28)

at processIncomingData (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:125:16)

at MessageStream._write (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:33:9)

at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:390:12)

at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:331:10)

at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:335:10)

at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:777:22)

at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28) {

ok: 0,

code: 66,

codeName: 'ImmutableField',

'$clusterTime': {

clusterTime: new Timestamp({ t: 1678502007, i: 4 }),

signature: {

hash: new Binary(Buffer.from("6d07aad2ad2644b91f653725c0f9ffbbcd035be7", "hex"), 0),

keyId: new Long("7148511101804609538")

}

},

operationTime: new Timestamp({ t: 1678502007, i: 4 }),

[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}

}

Function i added:

```
async function task(card, damage, interaction) {

  let profile = await profileModel.findOne({

    user: card.userID,

  });

  if (profile.task.length === 0) return;

  profile.task.forEach((e, i) => {

    if (e.complete !== true && e.type === "damage") {

      e.damageDone += damage;

    }

  });

  profile.markModified("task");

  await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate({ user: interaction.user.id }, profile);

  return profile;

}
```

Code:

```
await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(

              {

                user: winner,

              },

              {

                $inc: {

                  coins: bet,

                },

              }

            );

            await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(

              {

                user: loser,

              },

              {

                $inc: {

                  coins: -bet,

                },

              }

            );

            await interaction.followUp({

              embeds: [endEmbed],

            });

            if (winner === interaction.user.id) {

              if (profile.guild) {

                let guild = await guildModel.findOne({

                  name: profile.guild,

                });

                guild.chestXP += 15;

                await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(

                  {

                    user: interaction.user.id,

                  },

                  profile

                );

              }

              if (profile.task.length === 0) return;

              let profileTask = profile.task.filter(

                (v) =>

                  v.complete !== true && v.type === "badge" && v.id === "bc"

              );

              if (profileTask.length === 0) return;

              profileTask.forEach(async (element, int) => {

                let task = element;

                task.progress += 1;

                await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(

                  {

                    user: interaction.user.id,

                  },

                  profile

                );

              });

            }

          }
```

Trying to fix this and to not get the error anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think putting whole data object in update parameter (*profile*) causing this error

```
await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(

  {

    user: interaction.user.id,

  },

  profile

);
```

only try to include necessary updated fields in update parameter. it will fix your future hassles.

Answer (score 0):

My code was

```
 const amenity = await Amenity.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.params.id },
  );
```

Instead of

```
 const amenity = await Amenity.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.params.id },
    req.body,
    {
      new: true,
      runValidators: true,
    }
  );
```